# Get Central Coordinate from multiple coordinates in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, spatial

I want to get Central Coordinate from multiple latitude and longitute. How can I write this C# code in sql Stored procedure ?

```cs
// Get Central Coordinate from multiple latitude and longitute

public static async Task<GeoCoordinate> GetCentralGeoCoordinate(List<GeoCoordinate> geoCoordinates)
{
    if (geoCoordinates.Count == 1)
    {
        return geoCoordinates.Single();
    }

    double x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;

    foreach (var geoCoordinate in geoCoordinates)
    {
        var latitude = geoCoordinate.Latitude * Math.PI / 180;
        var longitude = geoCoordinate.Longitude * Math.PI / 180;

        x += Math.Cos(latitude) * Math.Cos(longitude);
        y += Math.Cos(latitude) * Math.Sin(longitude);
        z += Math.Sin(latitude);
    }

    var total = geoCoordinates.Count;
    x = x / total;
    y = y / total;
    z = z / total;

    var centralLongitude = Math.Atan2(y, x);
    var centralSquareRoot = Math.Sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    var centralLatitude = Math.Atan2(z, centralSquareRoot);

    return await Task.FromResult(new GeoCoordinate(centralLatitude * 180 / Math.PI, centralLongitude * 180 / Math.PI));
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The SQL Server [`geography`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/spatial-types-geography?view=sql-server-2017) data type already has an [`EnvelopeCenter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/envelopecenter-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-2017#examples) method, which I think should do what you want.

So provided you can construct a `geography` instance containing all of your points, you should be able to do this directly.

Note that the `geography` type is actually a .NET data type, called [`SqlGeography`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-smo-140.17283.0), which would have been a more *natural* type to use in your C# code rather than implementing geography logic yourself.

E.g. here's some sample SQL, just using (a truncated version of) your first two points:

```
select geography::STGeomFromText(
   'MULTIPOINT((-2.58316 51.418798),(-2.68319 51.419035))',
   4326).EnvelopeCenter()
```

(If you had presented your sample data as *text* rather than an image, I'd have done it for all of the points, but I don't need the typing practice thanks)

Comment: Hi @Damien I tried your solution in sql server but its returning output like this '0xE6100000010CF02D93679FB54940BCD485FCBD1005C0' . Could you please explain what went wrong. I am sharing link to the the files with coordinates also. I need only latitude and longitude value. URL: https://mab.to/eJOJkww76